# Is flooded system log dangerous problem

Tags: touchpad

My notebook has problem with touchpad, system log is flooded by error related to touchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784152
Is it dangerous to HDD/SSD to spam this kind of message?

Comment: Flooding logs can be form of DDoS attack. When system runs out of storage, it can freeze. So yes, that can be a problem of sorts

Comment: I don't think this gonna be fixed soon, whats the best solution ?